# woocommerce: get product detail form sku

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have made custom template file in wordpress , now i want to get product detail from product sku , need help how to do it is there woocommerce function to load product detail from sku .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post that provide a method for get product by sku:
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/find-product-sku-woocommerce/